# java optional parameters

Tags: java, optional-parameters

I want to write an average method in java such that it can consume N amount of items, returning the average of them:

My idea was:

```
    public static int average(int[] args){
        int total = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++){
            total = total + args[i];
        }
        return Math.round (total/args.length);
    }
//test it
average(1,2,3) // s**hould return 2.
```

how can I change my method to consume any amount of parameters instead of int[] args so can work the way I want ?
Cheers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Java 5 supports [varargs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html), which is what you want.

e.g.

```
public static int average(Integer... ints) {
   for (Integer i : ints) {
       // sum here...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since Java 5, there is a feature commonly called [varargs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) which achieves what is desired.

Here's a little example:

```
public static int add(int... nums) {
    int total = 0;

    for (int n : nums)
        total += n;

    return total;
}

public static void main(String[] s) {
    // The following prints "10"
    System.out.println(add(1, 2, 3, 4));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

function average() {

```
var total = 0;

if(arguments.length > 0) {

 for(var i = 0, n = arguments.length; i < n; i++) {

  total += parseFloat(arguments[i]);

 }

 total /= arguments.length;

}

return total;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here's the optional arguments version (almost no code changes...)

```
public class Spike2 {

  public static final void main(String argv[]) {
    System.out.println(average(1,2,3));
  }

   public static int average(int... args){
        int total = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++){
                total = total + args[i];
        }
        return Math.round (total/args.length);
    }

}
```

with iterator changes:

```
public class Spike2 {

  public static final void main(String argv[]) {
    System.out.println(average(1,2,3));
  }

   public static int average(int... args){
        int total = 0;
        for(int i:  args){
                total = total + i;
        }
        return Math.round (total/args.length);
    }

}
```