# Evaluating multiple variable together in if condition

Tags: java, if-statement

I was wondering whether its possible in java to evaluate multiple variables together in `if-else` condition like in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504638/evaluate-multiple-variables-in-one-if-statement).

**actual code**

```
if(abc!=null && xyz!=null)
{//...}
```

**dummy code**

```
if(abc && xyz !=null)
{// will it be possible}
```

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible in Java.

Comment: Impossible !. You can see here: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-if-statements-in-java.html

Comment: @RongNK Yes I agree with you. it was just a doubt for me :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the only way this would work is if `abc` was a boolean (and it wouldn't do what you're hoping it would do, it would simply test if abc == true). There is no way to compare one thing to multiple things in Java.

Answer (score 20):

**FIRST DRAFT**

You can write smth like this:

```
boolean notNull(Object item) { 
    return item != null;
}
```

then you could use it like:

```
if (notNull(abc) && notNull(xyz)) {
    //...
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I came up with a new idea, write function using *varargs* like:

```
boolean notNull(Object... args) {
    for (Object arg : args) {
        if (arg == null) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

usage: (you can pass to function multiple arguments)

```
if (notNull(abc, xyz)) {
    //...
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

The best approach is to use library [apache commons ObjectUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html),
it contains  several ready to use methods like:

- [`allNotNull(Object... values)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#allNotNull-java.lang.Object...-),
- [`anyNotNull(Object... values)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#anyNotNull-java.lang.Object...-)
- or [`firstNonNull(T... values)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#firstNonNull-T...-)

Comment: How is this any different?

Comment: @squiguy actually at many places for validation purpose I have to write the same thing, so thats why I asked whether if is there any future plan in java for such kind :)

Comment: At least make it `return (item != null);`.

Answer (score 1):

It's *Impossible* in java, you can use `Varargs`:

```
public boolean  checkAnything(Object args...){
  for(Object obj args){
    if(...)
  }
  return ....;
}
```

**See also:**

- [Varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html)
- [String… parameter in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048744/string-parameter-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to that in Java. Instead you can do something like this:-

```
public boolean checkForNulls(Object... args){
    List<Object> test = new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(args));
    return test.contains(null); // Check if even 1 of the objects was null.
}
```

If any of the items is `null`, then the method will return `true`, else it'll return `false`. You can use it as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO First is the better way and possible way.

Coming to second way ..if they are `boolean` values

```
if(abc  && xyz )
{//...}
```